# how to GET a variable from a url without a variable

Tags: php, parsing, url, get

I am trying to GET the **int** from the following string

> member.php?**3**-bradthor

I have tried using the following code

```
    $query = parse_url($str, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$intval = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",' $query');
```

However I don't think this is a fool proof solution?
what Imporovements could I make to this code/what code should I use to get the integer from the above string.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `' $query'` variables do not get parsed in single quotes.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the int"? `preg_replace` isn't used to get anything, it's used to replace it. Are you trying to return a matched string or replace it?

Comment: That completely depends on what the url can look like and the exact result you need.

Comment: `$query = (int)parse_url($str, PHP_URL_QUERY);`

Comment: i am trying to get a variable from the url......then I want to replace everything in that url with nothing except the int above...anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
$str = 'member.php?3-bradthor';
$query = parse_url($str, PHP_URL_QUERY);

$intval = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$query);// remove single quotes.

echo $intval;
```

Working [demo](https://eval.in/504728)

Answer (score 0):

Because of how integers are parsed in PHP you can simple use

```
$query = parse_url('member.php?3-bradthor', PHP_URL_QUERY);
$intval = intval($query);
```

if will work only when number in the begining of string.

Less dirty solution is to use for example mod_rewrite.